# Limited Download Throughput on single Desktop PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, download, throughput

So I just moved into a new home and have been setting up the internet here, but it seems like my desktop does not like the new internet environment. Originally, I tested to see if it was the Ubiquiti gear I had set up, but every other `hardwired device was getting the expected 500-600 Mbps whereas the desktop was getting somewhere between 140-180 Mbps.` This result stays consistent among the devices whether I plug the connection directly into the modem, USG-3P (Router), or US-16-150W (Switch). The Desktop in question is using a Realtek GBE Family Controller with a confirmed 1.0 Gbps LAN connection on both the UniFi controller and the native Windows 10 Network Adapter Properties.

**Desktop OS: Windows 10 Pro**

**Laptop OS: Windows 10 Home**

This is what I have tried so far:

- ipconfig /flushdns
- Used both ISP and Google DNS
- Enabled/disabled QoS Packet Scheduler service
- Updating Realtek Drivers via Realtek's site
- Used MSI Live Update to update drivers

By the way, the upstream for this desktop is actually the expected amount (25Mbps), which makes it all the more confusing for me. So far, my Googling has failed me. Any troubleshooting ideas?

**Update 1:** 
Safe mode with networking also nets me the same results around 140-160 Mbps downstream.

**Update 2:**
I have not yet done the test a Linux LiveUSB yet, but I have purchased an Intel-based chipset as suggested below, and I have gotten some interesting results. This test was done between the same laptop and desktop. The Desktop is running Windows 10 Pro, and the laptop is running Windows 10 Home.

iperf3 results below:

On the new Intel adapter (Jeirdus with Intel Chipset 82546 Dual Port Gigabit 8492MT NIC):

*Downstream*

```
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  31.5 MBytes   264 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  31.8 MBytes   266 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  31.6 MBytes   265 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  31.6 MBytes   265 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  31.5 MBytes   264 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  31.1 MBytes   261 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  31.6 MBytes   266 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  31.8 MBytes   266 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  31.2 MBytes   262 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  31.8 MBytes   266 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   316 MBytes   265 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   315 MBytes   265 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

*Upstream*

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  78.4 MBytes   658 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  80.4 MBytes   675 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  80.7 MBytes   677 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  81.3 MBytes   682 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  81.3 MBytes   682 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  81.4 MBytes   683 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  77.3 MBytes   649 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  81.2 MBytes   681 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  80.2 MBytes   673 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  81.4 MBytes   683 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   804 MBytes   674 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   804 MBytes   674 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

On the old, motherboard Realtek adapter (Z97 PC Mate):

*Downstream*

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   113 MBytes   945 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   113 MBytes   945 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   113 MBytes   946 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   113 MBytes   946 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   113 MBytes   946 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   113 MBytes   947 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   113 MBytes   946 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   113 MBytes   945 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.10 GBytes   944 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.10 GBytes   943 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

*Upstream*

```
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   110 MBytes   919 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   109 MBytes   911 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   106 MBytes   886 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   111 MBytes   932 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   112 MBytes   935 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   111 MBytes   935 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   111 MBytes   934 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   111 MBytes   933 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   111 MBytes   932 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   111 MBytes   934 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.08 GBytes   925 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.08 GBytes   925 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Even though the throughput on LAN seems to be higher on the old adapter, the Intel adapter seems to be much closer to the WAN downstream throughput on the Desktop. Perhaps the Realtek adapter is getting false throughput? Either way, if anyone has further troubleshooting steps for getting my WAN speed back up for this particular Desktop I would be very grateful.

Comment: Suggest you replicate your speed test after booting from a Linux LiveUSB to assure there's no OS misconfiguration.

Comment: Realtek NICs are very budget and dont have the appropriate buffers to perform at high speed. Replace your NIC.

Comment: Would a gigabit USB ethernet adapter work for a replacement?

Comment: @Kai - Can you be more specific? PCI-e network cards are cheap far better than a usb device

Comment: Sorry, I may not have edited out the outdated details. I couldn't use a PCI-E card because my 1080Ti fans would be sitting right next to the adapter and I didn't want to be blowing hot air into the chip point blank. I ended up going with a PCI NIC, which from what I read would be fine for anything under a 1Gbps connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I somehow didn't try to do an adapter reset with the following commands:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int tcp reset
netsh int ip reset
```

Rebooting after this solved my problem.